# Pushing variables to a dropdown in GoogleApps Scripting

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-apps-script-editor

I am trying to push some variables to a dropdown using GoogleApps Scripting. Running into a 'Malformed HTML content' error. It definitely has to do with how I am writing 'option value=', but I can't figure it out. 
Thank you for any help!

```
<html>
   <head>
      <base target="_top">
   </head>
   <body>
      <select>
      <? Logger.log("data "+data) ?>
      <? for (var i = 0; i < data; i++) {  ?>
      <?= "<option value=\"" + data[i].name + "\">" + data[i].name + "</option>" ?>
      <? } ?>
      </select>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do this in a template? Use a page load handler coupled with `google.script.run`. There are examples of this on Google's `HtmlService` communication guide. Doing so would then mean you could very easily *update* this option list based on new data, without requiring the page to be refreshed.

Comment: SO more like this? It still doesn't seem to be working, but I am sure I did something wrong.
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

  <head>

    <base target="_top">

  </head>

    <script>

    function createDropdown(courses) {

      var div = document.getElementById('output');

        div.innerHTML = courses;  

    }

    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createDropdown)

          .getCourses();

    </script>
  
   
   <body>
   <select>
    <div id="output"></div>
    </select>
  </body>
</html>

Comment: Yeah, something like that :) Probably you want to only call your async loading scripts after the page has initially loaded, as is shown here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices#load_data_asynchronously_not_in_templates

Answer (score 0):

Instead of joining the strings inside of a  block, write the html and  output the relevant strings where needed.

```
  <select>
  <? for (var i = 0; i < data; i++) {  ?>
     <option value="<?= data[i].name ?>"> <?=data[i].name?></option>
  <? } ?>
  </select>
```

Note that this still might give you unexpected results depending on what your data[i].name values contain (EG if it contains a quote), so you might want to escape it inside the `value=""` property.

Comment: When I quote out the data[i].name, it just puts that exact string in the dropdown. How do I actually get the variable to be written?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, I would need to see the code. Note that this approach to generating your drop down is perfectly valid, I've done it this way many times. The google.script.run approach is also a fine way to approach it.

Answer (score 0):

The way you're doing it isn't gonna cut it. Use [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run):

google.script.run is an asynchronous client-side JavaScript API available in HTML-service pages that can call server-side Apps Script functions. To interact with dialogs or sidebars in Google Docs, Sheets, or Forms from client-side code, use google.script.host. For more information, see the guide to communicating with server functions in HTML service.

sample snippet:

**CODE.GS**

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
}

function doSomething() {
  Logger.log('I was called!');
}
```

Then on your **INDEX.HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
      google.script.run.doSomething();
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Probably in this example you want to show the immediate usefulness to the OP, e.g. use a success handler to change some client HTML. Perhaps the client code starts with "I waved at the server", and it gets changed to include "The server function said hello" when the page finishes loading